# Is there a way to play a sound when a tab or page received new data?

Tags: google-chrome

Say (for instance) you're using twitter and you want to know if there's a new tweet without having to constantly watch it's tab to appear the number of new tweets, **by playing a sound**.

Is there an extension for that?